# Solution of this linear algebra system?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading about Gauss elimination and I'm stuck on this problem:

[image]

So I started by adding -1 * first row to the second row and third row to produce:

$$a_0 + a_1 + a_2 = 4$$
$$a_1 + 3a_2 = -4$$
$$2a_1 + 8a_2 = 8$$

Is that right? From here where do I go?

**EDIT**
Is this right? Then add the multiple of -2 of the second row to the third row to get:

$$a_0 + a_1 + a_2 = 4$$
$$a_1 + 3a_2 = -4$$
$$2a_2 = 16$$

So:

$$a_0 = 24$$
$$a_1 = -28$$
$$a_2 = 8$$

Does that look right?

Comment: It's OK, continue eliminating $a_1$ from the third row, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In augmented matrix form we have

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&   1&   1&  4\\
      1&   2&  4&  0\\
      1&  3& 9&  12
    \end{array}\right] \to \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&   1&   1&  4\\
      0&   1&  3&  -4\\
      0&  2& 8&  8
    \end{array}\right] \to  \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&   1&   1&  4\\
      0&   1&  3&  -4\\
      0&  0& 2&  16
    \end{array}\right]$$

that is

- $a_2=8$
- $a_1=-28$
- $a_0=24$